# How to restart Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello all actually this question is very old and wherever i have read i have found two solutions one is to use [shutdown api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html) which is now deprecated so i am wondering how to do it now, the second solution i found was to use below command

> sudo service elasticsearch restart

which i did use but above command is not starting all of my nodes. I have 3 nodes i ran above command on my first node and it restarted but i tried the same command on my other two nodes but then when i tried to connect to my elasticsearch then i got below error.

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Now can anyone please tell me why i am getting above connection refused error i have also set

> network.host: 0.0.0.0

in my elasticsearch.yml file, also as **shutdown api** is deprecated what can be the proper way of restarting an elastic cluster.

Please help me wherever i go i find only these two things and they are not working for me.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: no there is nothing in logs i saw in both elasticsearch.log, elasticsearch-cluster.log

Comment: First try `sudo service stop elasticsearch` and check if elasticsearch actally stopped via `ps` command. If it did not stop try to kill it. Then start again `sudo service start elasticsearch`.

Comment: once type sudo service elasticsearch status on other two  nodes and also see the logs